# Docker-Compose SQL Server database persist data after host restart

Tags: sql-server, docker-compose

My Docker-Compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
 db:
  image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-CU8
  ports: 
    - 1433:1433
  deploy:
    mode: replicated
    replicas: 1 
  environment:
    - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=SuperStrongSqlAdminPassword)(*£)($£)
  volumes:
    - /home/mssql/:/var/opt/mssql/
    - /var/opt/mssql/data
```

As you can see I have a volume mapped to a directory on the host machine: /home/msqql:/var/opt/mssql/

If I do: `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml [stack name]`.

The server starts and I can see data is written to the hosts directory: `/home/mssql/*`.

I then connect to the server and create a database, tables and add some data.

If I then kill the stack using `docker stack rm [stack name]`, or restart the host for maintenance reasons etc.

When SQL Server starts up again, although the `/home/mssql/*` still contains the files created by the server initially, if I connect to the server the database/tables/data is gone.

Do I have to re-attach the database when the server restarts somehow, or something else I'm missing maybe?

Thanks